# How can I hide Windows Defender alerts on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-defender

Is it possible to disable the visual alerts of Windows Defender on Windows 8 but still leave the program activated? If so, how?

Comment: If you are not notified of a detected infection what good is the program?

Comment: It is a lab environment where we're developing something. Want to leave Defender activated but don't want the constant alerts.

Answer (score 2):

1. In `msconfig/services` you need to uncheck Windows Defender.
2. Now in `msconfig/startup` you need to uncheck Microsoft Windows Operating System where the command line is

   > '%Program Files%\Windows Defender\MSASCui.exe -hide'.
3. Restart your PC to enable the changes.

Comment: Won't this disable Defender as a whole? I just want to hide the alerts.

Comment: No, Just alerts will be hidden.